# How do you call the way to insert PHP code in an HTML archive?

Tags: php, html, embed

here below explains how to embed PHP code in HTML files. Is there any name to referrer that way of writing PHP ?

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html

Javi

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I don't really get your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the syntax in that article that looks like this:

```
<?php if(conditions): ?>
... HTML CODE ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's called the [Alternative Syntax for Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).  Unfortunately, that doesn't really roll off one's tongue very well.

The article also shows an example of the [short open tag](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag):

```
<?=$var?>
```

Comment: You should however avoid the usage of short open tags as it is considered bad practice. Use <?php .. code .. ?> instead.

Comment: @MAINERROR: Yes, but do you know why short open tags are bad practice?

Comment: Because of the php ini. In some configs short_open_tag might not be turned on. At least thats the reason I knew.

Comment: @MAINERROR: The short tags are also invalid XML, so if you use them, it's impossible to validate your page as XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You just took it wrong. It is not PHP being embedded in HTML, but HTML being embedded in PHP.
To run PHP code a PHP interpreter is required. And usual browser doesn't have one.
Thus, you can add PHP code to HTML archive but it just won't work.

While embedding itself is called [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)